# I want to open other specific Activity

Tags: android

After executing the below code `Activity` of my app gets closed but till component name, code is working fine:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo("com.package.address",PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
ActivityInfo[] activitiesInfos = packageInfo.activities;
ActivityInfo activityToLaunch=activitiesInfos[0]; //<< activity which want enter code here to enter code herestart

// Create ComponentName object using packageName and activity name
ComponentName compName=new ComponentName(
                                     activityToLaunch.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                     activityToLaunch.name);
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setComponent(compName);
startActivity(intent);
```

While debugging cursor come till `startActivity(intent)` but after this activity will terminate

Comment: You are trying to launch another app?

Comment: SecurityException will be thrown if trying to launch another app; otherwise i get no problem. Is it what you want (launch another app)? @NishanKhadka

Comment: Nope, I am asking you if you are trying to launch a specific activity of another application.

Comment: @NishanKhadka ok, i understand what you want, please check my answer, and feel free to leave a comment

Comment: oh, i have mis-tagged you, sorry Nishan

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Ok, please try below:

1.) if you just want to start the launcher activity of another app:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (intent != null) {
    // if package is found; otherwise null
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

2.) if you want to start a specific activity (note: you need to know its full name and it should be set `android:exported="true"` in AndroidManifest)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// xxx and yyy representing its sub package if any
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address", "com.package.address.xxx.yyy.FullActivityName"));
startActivity(intent);
```